# How to append values in multi-directional array

Tags: arrays, swift

I am reading some values generated by different beacons, let's say beacon 1& beacon 2. I want to collect values of each beacon separately.

I think if there is a way to use a where statement would be easier like 
get values where beacon = 1 and then where beacon = 2

As far as I'm understanding: 
First, I created the multidirectional array:

```
var values = [[Int]]()
var tempBeacon = [Int]
```

Then, a for loop to collect some values for i beacons:

```
for i in 0...beaconCount-1 {
   let beacon = beacons[i]
   values[i] = tempBeacon.append(beacons[i].value)
}
```

Thank you guys, and excuse my programming skills as I'm a beginner.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would tend to approach this problem as a dictionary of arrays.  Each key in the dictionary would represent the beacon and the array stored at each key would contain the values for that beacon.  Using a dictionary makes it easy to find the beacon for which you need to add a new entry.

Here's functional example from a playground:

```
func addBeaconEntry(beaconName: String, newValue: Int) {
    if beaconData[beaconName] == nil {
        // Beacon is not yet in dictionary, so we create an array
        beaconData[beaconName] = [Int]()
    }
    beaconData[beaconName]?.append(newValue)
}

// Dictionary of array of integers for beacon values
var beaconData = [String: [Int]]()
addBeaconEntry(beaconName: "beacon 1", newValue: 10)
addBeaconEntry(beaconName: "beacon 2", newValue: 20)
addBeaconEntry(beaconName: "beacon 3", newValue: 30)
addBeaconEntry(beaconName: "beacon 1", newValue: 1120)

print(beaconData)
print("Data for beacon 1:")
print(beaconData["beacon 1"] ?? [0])
```

Comment: Thanks, exactly the peace I was missing. I like your approach.